# Intermediate tutorial for OpenGL as implemented in Qt

Tags: qt, opengl, graphics, 3d

I am making an interface for a free-and-open project I'm working on. I know that eventually I'll need it to do some heavy lifting with 3D graphics, so I'll need access to the GPU. I stumbled upon the Qt framework and its use of OpenGL. Their cross-platform properties are very appealing to me, and I've learned a lot about building run of the mill / plumbing kinda stuff on Qt, but using OpenGL is more challenging than I'd have hoped.

I've rooted around in several books and on Google for good tutorials, but they jump around, or don't seem to quite work when I try to implement them.  The examples presented in the IDE have a lot of bells and whistles, and almost none of it is explained.  When I tried implementing the example from "C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4", it didn't compile properly.  There are a set of somewhat famous "NeHe" tutorials on OpenGL, but they are not implemented with Qt and the companion series on made by "The Independent Qt Tutorial" is very brief.

I would be very grateful for an example that goes very slowly and introduces Qt and OpenGL together.  There is [a blog entry](http://www.deder.at/wordpress/?p=132) that made things a lot clearer when I read it from a man named Daniel Eder.  But he hasn't actually written code in that part of the discussion.

Specifically, if I could just get something really simple working in Qt like a cube I could rotate or maybe something more sophisticated like a sphere, I'd have enough traction to understand other tutorials.  I definitely want to do the coding myself, but I'm having trouble even getting to the place where I can fool around, haha.

Comment: The problem with asking for Qt based OpenGL tutorials is that fundamentally they have nothing to do with each other. And any tutorial which would introduce them together would have to seriously glance over important aspects of either one. I would just recommend you pick up a good OpenGL book/resource. (Note, NeHe is not what I would call good) In the end, all Qt does is wrap around some of the OpenGL stuff, providing a simple to use widget for your OpenGL context.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Stack Overflow is not a Link Farm or Search Engine.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128549/164572)

Comment: http://www.digitalfanatics.org/projects/qt_tutorial/chapter14.html  This is something I found by looking up "QT and OpenGL" in google.  please do some searching on your own as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some places with **tutorials and examples**:

- There is also a [Wiki](http://qt-project.org/wiki/NeHe_in_Qt) in the Qt Dev network that you may find useful. I particularly suggest [Wesley Stessens's](http://wesley.vidiqatch.org/) blog that helped me personally a lot.
- [Nehe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/your_first_polygon/13002/) website provide a good tutorial where you can find some of the examples given ported to Qt.
- There are also many QtOpenGL examples in [Qt Creator/SDK](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads) that can be handy. I strongly suggest you take a look at them as they are very simple to understand and to play around with.

With that my next step was to read these two **books**:

- C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4, 3rd edition
- OpenGL Programming Guide: The Official Guide to Learning OpenGL, 7th edition

I have also been very happy when looking for help in the related **Doc's/Reference manuals, etc.**:

- [Qt Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/)
- [QtOpenGL module](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtopengl.html)
- [OpenGL Documentation](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/)

At this level, you may solve your implementation problem straight away : )

Good luck.

Comment: This was it!!    Thank you so much.  Wesley's blog was exactly what I looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help. I am personally waiting for the 8th edition of OpenGL Programming Guide coming out this [December](http://www.amazon.com/OpenGL-Programming-Guide-Official-Learning/dp/0321773039/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1339442666&sr=1-2). I hope they will let down the deppreciated functions and come up with new examples as they say "85% new material".

Comment: Could any of you post a code of 1st chapter here(or somewhere else)..? Wesley's page is down. Trying since last 2 days.. I am looking for framework only like NeHe's..